# C# MVC: List<string> becomes System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] which becomes System.String[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a c# MVC mvc webapplication but i have some troubles finding out why a property in my model goes from List to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] when passed from view to controller.

In my view I am listing some of my models and provides for each of them a Actionlink which calls the method ContinueStatus() providing the model object (status) in the parameter:

```
@foreach (DriftsstatusModel status in (List<DriftsstatusModel>)ViewData["activeStatuses"])
{
  @Html.ActionLink("Fortsæt", "ContinueStatus", "Home", status, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-lg", @style = "font-size:x-large" })
}
```

When I place a breakpoint in the above and scroll over status (the model object) I correctly see that the property SelectedProducts is a `List<string>` with count 1. However, when the actionlink button is clicked and the controller method ContinueStatus() is called, the property SelectedProducts has changed to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] and instead of count = 1 it says {string[1]}. The controller method:

```
public ActionResult ContinueStatus(DriftsstatusModel driftsStatus)
    {
        // Does something, but not with SelectedProducts
        return RedirectToAction("Index", driftsStatus);
    }
```

After the controler method Index returns to the view now SelectedProducts has changed to "System.String[]" from System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] and still shows {string[1]}. Because SelectedProducts has changed I do not know how to access the one string which should currently be in it. This means the else branch is always chosen in the following part of my view:

```
<optgroup label="DLI">
   @foreach (string product in dliProducts)
   {
      if (Model.SelectedProducts.Contains(product))
      {
         <option selected>@product</option>
      }
      else
      {
         <option>@product</option>
      }
   }
</optgroup>
```

Why does this happen and how can I correct it?

---

I wil try to answer some of the questions.

I am making an web application that should be used to send email and sms to notify ppl when a product has an error, for example that you cannot login to a service (product). This status email/sms can be started, continued and ended and thus there is a need to load earlier information of that specific status so you can change it and then either continue it (error is net yet fixed) or close it (error is fixed, so last status update).

The model DriftsstatusModel holds all of this information and have the property

```
public List<string> SelectedProducts { get; set; }
```

which holds selected options in a multiselect. In my view I then show all the active statusses like so (removed button styling etc.):

```
@foreach (DriftsstatusModel status in (List<DriftsstatusModel>)ViewData["activeStatuses"])
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Fortsæt", "ContinueStatus", "Home", status, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-lg", @style = "font-size:x-large" })
   @Html.ActionLink("Afslut", "EndStatus", "Home", status, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-lg", @style = "font-size:x-large" })
}
```

here it should be noted that ViewData["activeStatuses"] is populated in the controller where i get the DriftsstatusModel instances from a DB and its works as expected getting all the prior information. It is also here that status (a instance of DriftsstatusModel) have the "right" SelectedProducts where i in debug mode can see the count and acces the elements.

So when the continue button is clicked the two following controller actions is called:

```
public ActionResult ContinueStatus(DriftsstatusModel driftsStatus)
{
   // Does something, but not with SelectedProducts
   return RedirectToAction("Index",driftsStatus);
}
public ActionResult Index(DriftsstatusModel driftsStatus)
{
        // Does something, but not with driftsStatus.SelectedProducts 
        ViewData["activeStatuses"] = statusDbHandler.GetActiveStatusses();
        return View(driftsStatus);
}
```

Now all the information in the status should be loaded into the fields in the view where one is a multiselect:

```
<select class="selectpicker w-100" data-val="true" id="SelectedProducts" name="SelectedProducts" multiple>
            <optgroup label="DLI">
                @foreach (string product in dliProducts)
                {
                    if (Model.SelectedProducts.Contains(product))
                    {
                        <option selected>@product</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option>@product</option>
                    }
                }
            </optgroup>
```

In this multiselect i check if SelectedProducts already contains some of the options and if it does i want these options to already be selected and thus:

```
<option SELECTED>@product</option>
```

However, because SelectedProducts somehow is not the same here as in place where i list the active statusses this is never true. Why SelectedProducts has changed i just can't figure out...

Hope this helps

Comment: First List<string> is 100% the same as System.COllections.Generic.List'1[System.String]... They are ONE and the SAME.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve... But everything is working as it should from the C# perspective... I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by Model.SelectedProducts.Contains call.... That is just verifying if the string sored inside the variable "product" is contained withing the SelectedProducts property.

Comment: You need to provide the code for the class that contains the property called SeletedProduct.... also there NO implicit conversion between List<string> and string[] so it is impossible that it "just changed" by itself

Comment: You also need to show where the @model is being assigned in your view. We need to see the class that acts as Model for that view.  We need to see the entire Model class.

Comment: The only relevant code is the html view, the class that acts as model and also the declaration of dliProducts... since you are doing a foreach on it.

Comment: Please see my answer :)

Comment: Delete your "asnwer" as it is not an answer but just an edit to your question. So edit your question and add the things we asked for which is the complete class that acts as model and the Html View

Comment: Also "Contains" in a List<string> is case sensitive.

Comment: The only way we can help you is we can replicate the issue on our own computers.